# Why parallel for of openmp does not work for vectorized color space conversion?

Tags: c++, x86, openmp, avx, icc

I have vectorized the color space conversion algorithm (RGB to YCbCr). when I don't use threads (`#pragma omp parallel for`) everything seems to be fine. But when I try to use threads it can not improve the performance of the vectorized version of my codes (**It also disimproves**).

Threads speedups the scalar code, the auto-vectorized code and the OpenMP SIMDized code (`#pragma omp parallel for simd`)

I have no idea what is going on and need your help.

Thanks in advance

I use fedora 31, Intel corei7 6700HQ, 12GB RAM, ICC 19.0.3 (-Ofast `[-no-vec]` -qopenmp -xHOST

Codes are as follows:

**Scalar:**

```
//Scalar for basline
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX1 512
#define MAX2 MAX1


float  __attribute__(( aligned(32))) image_r[MAX1][MAX2], image_g[MAX1][MAX2], image_b[MAX1][MAX2], image_y[MAX1][MAX2], image_cb[MAX1][MAX2], image_cr[MAX1][MAX2];
float coeff_RTY[3][3] = {{0.299, 0.587, 0.114},{-0.169, -0.331, 0.500},{0.500, -0.419, -0.081}};

inline void fill_float(float a[MAX1][MAX1])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<MAX1; i++){

        for(j=0; j<MAX2; j++){
            a[i][j] = (i+j+100)%256;

        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    fill_float(image_r);
    fill_float(image_g);
    fill_float(image_b);

    int i, j;
    long t1,t2,min=100000000000000;
    do{
        t1=_rdtsc();
        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for( i=0; i<MAX1; i++){
        for( j=0; j<MAX2; j++){

        image_y[i][j] = coeff_RTY[0][0]*image_r[i][j] + coeff_RTY[0][1]*image_g[i][j] + coeff_RTY[0][2]*image_b[i][j];
        image_cb[i][j] = coeff_RTY[1][0]*image_r[i][j] + coeff_RTY[1][1]*image_g[i][j] + coeff_RTY[1][2]*image_b[i][j] + 128;
        image_cr[i][j] = coeff_RTY[2][0]*image_r[i][j] + coeff_RTY[2][1]*image_g[i][j] + coeff_RTY[2][2]*image_b[i][j] + 128;

        }
        }

        t2=_rdtsc();

        if((t2-t1)<min){
            min=t2-t1;
            printf("\n%li", t2-t1);
        }
    }while(1);
    printf("%f", image_y[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);
    printf("%f", image_cb[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);
    printf("%f", image_cr[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);
    return 0;
}
```

And the **vectorized** version using AVX (floating point):

```
//AVX
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#define MAX1 512
#define MAX2 MAX1

float  __attribute__(( aligned(32))) image_r[MAX1][MAX2], image_g[MAX1][MAX2], image_b[MAX1][MAX2], image_y[MAX1][MAX2], image_cb[MAX1][MAX2], image_cr[MAX1][MAX2];
float coeff_RTY[3][3] = {{0.299, 0.587, 0.114},{-0.169, -0.331, 0.500},{0.500, -0.419, -0.081}};

inline void fill_float(float a[MAX1][MAX1])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<MAX1; i++){

        for(j=0; j<MAX2; j++){
            a[i][j] = (i+j+100)%256;

        }
    }
}
int main()
{


    //program variables:
    //calculate filter coeff or use an existing one
    __m256 vec_c[3][3], vec_128;
    __m256 vec_r, vec_g, vec_b, vec_y, vec_cb, vec_cr;
    __m256 vec_t[3][3], vec_sum;

    vec_c[0][0] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[0][0]);
    vec_c[0][1] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[0][1]);
    vec_c[0][2] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[0][2]);

    vec_c[1][0] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[1][0]);
    vec_c[1][1] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[1][1]);
    vec_c[1][2] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[1][2]);

    vec_c[2][0] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[2][0]);
    vec_c[2][1] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[2][1]);
    vec_c[2][2] = _mm256_set1_ps(coeff_RTY[2][2]);

    vec_128 = _mm256_set1_ps(128);
    //iorder to avoid optimization for zero values
    fill_float(image_r);
    fill_float(image_g);
    fill_float(image_b);
    int i, j=0;
    long t1,t2,min=100000000000000;
    do{
        t1=_rdtsc();

        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for( i=0; i<MAX1; i++){
            for( j=0; j<MAX2; j+=8){
            //_mm_prefetch(&image_r[i][j+8],_MM_HINT_T0);
            //_mm_prefetch(&image_g[i][j+8],_MM_HINT_T0);
            //_mm_prefetch(&image_b[i][j+8],_MM_HINT_T0);
            vec_r = _mm256_load_ps(&image_r[i][j]);
            vec_g = _mm256_load_ps(&image_g[i][j]);
            vec_b = _mm256_load_ps(&image_b[i][j]);


            vec_t[0][0] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, vec_c[0][0]);
            vec_t[0][1] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_g, vec_c[0][1]);
            vec_t[0][2] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_b, vec_c[0][2]);

            vec_t[1][0] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, vec_c[1][0]);
            vec_t[1][1] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_g, vec_c[1][1]);
            vec_t[1][2] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_b, vec_c[1][2]);

            vec_t[2][0] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_r, vec_c[2][0]);
            vec_t[2][1] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_g, vec_c[2][1]);
            vec_t[2][2] = _mm256_mul_ps(vec_b, vec_c[2][2]);

            //vec_y = vec_t[0][0] + vec_t[0][1] + vec_t[0][2]
            vec_sum = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[0][0], vec_t[0][1]);
            vec_y = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[0][2], vec_sum);

            //vec_cb = vec_t[1][0] + vec_t[1][1] + vec_t[1][2] +128
            vec_sum = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[1][0], vec_t[1][1]);
            vec_sum = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[1][2], vec_sum);
            vec_cb = _mm256_add_ps(vec_128, vec_sum);

            //vec_cr = vec_t[2][0] + vec_t[2][1] + vec_t[2][2] +128
            vec_sum = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[2][0], vec_t[2][1]);
            vec_sum = _mm256_add_ps(vec_t[2][2], vec_sum);
            vec_cr = _mm256_add_ps(vec_128, vec_sum);

            _mm256_stream_ps(&image_y[i][j], vec_y);
            _mm256_stream_ps(&image_cb[i][j], vec_cb);
            _mm256_stream_ps(&image_cr[i][j], vec_cr);

            }
        }
        t2=_rdtsc();

        if((t2-t1)<min){
            min=t2-t1;
            printf("\n%li", t2-t1);
        }
    }while(1);

    //inorder to avoid optimization for non used values
    printf("%f", image_y[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);
    printf("%f", image_cb[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);
    printf("%f", image_cr[MAX1/2][MAX2/2]);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The best recorded cycles for 128x128 image size is as follows:

---

**Single core:**

```
Scalar code: 88k
Auto-vectorized: 59k
Vectorized using intrinsics: **21k** 
vectorized by #pragma omp simd: 59k
```

**Multiple cores:**

```
Scalar code: 25k
Auto-vectorized: 13k
Vectorized using intrinsics: **226k** 
vectorized by #pragma omp .. simd: 22k
```

---

For 1024x1024 image size is as follows:

---

**Single core:**

```
Scalar code: 7M
Auto-vectorized: 3M
Vectorized using intrinsics: **3M** 
vectorized by #pragma omp simd: 3M
```

**Multiple cores:**

```
Scalar code: 6M
Auto-vectorized: 6M
Vectorized using intrinsics: **15M** 
vectorized by #pragma omp parallel for simd: 8M
```

Comment: Just because something is threaded doesn't mean it'll be faster than a single-threaded version.

Comment: i7-6700HQ can (nearly?) saturate memory bandwidth with a single core.  In general I'd expect a small speedup from parallelization if you code was already maxing out single-core memory bandwidth, and a bigger speedup if not.  Threading overhead may be killing you if you're repeating a small amount of work, especially where your RDTSC timing includes the thread dispatch overhead.

Comment: `_mm256_stream_ps` is also suspicious.  512*512 * 4B/float = 1MiB of cache footprint per 2D array, or 6MiB total, which fits in the L3 cache of your CPU.  Bypassing L3 to store to DRAM means more slowdown.  I'm not sure why exactly more cores doing that would suck more, except maybe single-core turbo vs. all-core turbo limits reducing the uncore (L3/ring bus) clock speed.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've changed `_mm256_stream_pa` to _mm256_store_ps` but it's impact isn't significant. I just wonder why scalar code on multiple cores yields speedup but vectorized code slows down terribly!! What is your suggestion for RDTSC timing in order to avoid the thread dispatch overhead?

Comment: If scalar doesn't auto-vectorize well, it won't be memory bound so it will benefit from multiple cores.  If a vectorized version is already saturating memory bandwidth with one core, using more won't help.  You haven't shown any absolute times so we can see the difference between scalar source and vectorized source without OpenMP and with OpenMP.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've updated the question. And I'm recording times for 1024x1024 sizes

Comment: If your testing is limited to a single selection of number of threads and pinning, that should be 1 thread per core with omp_places=cores.  It's entirely possible that scalar code may achieve peak performance with more threads than simd code.  As hinted above, you may need to test 2 threads, both pinned to specific cores as well as floating among cores but not hyperthreads.   This is hardly a new subject.  In the early days of AMD multi-core CPUs, there was little benefit in combining simd and threads (nor OpenMP and MPI).  Likewise, the question of whether a cluster should disable hyperthread

Comment: omp_places takes longer to come into effect when entering a Windows parallel region than on other OS.

Comment: @Martin: using bullet lists for groups of results would probably be easier to read.  (Take less space and group better).  `* entry` is the markdown.  Also, rounding your numbers to fewer significant figures would be easier to see orders of magnitude.  e.g. 25k.  I was stopping to count digits so I could tell if one number was somewhat larger or almost 10x smaller.

Comment: @Martin Honestly your inputs are fairly small so it's interesting you see any speed-up at all. That said, perhaps it is also worth looking at how you distribute the work between threads, it would probably be wise to add `num_threads(2) schedule(static, MAX1/2)` or something along those lines. I would be curious to see the results in that case.

Comment: @Qubit, using `omp_set_dynamic(0); omp_set_num_threads(2);` for `MAX1=1024` is about `12M` cycles. reduced `3M`cycles. but not yet good.

Comment: @Qubit, by playing with numbers got yet better results!!! `omp_set_dynamic(3); omp_set_num_threads(12);` `MAX1=128` number of cycles are `28k` and `MAX1=1024` are `3M` and I think these results are fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with different ideas, the problem was solved by adding the following line of OpenMP statements before the `#pragma omp parallel for`

`omp_set_dynamic(3);`

Therefore the results are:

> Vectorized using intrinsics and 
>    Multi-core:

```
MAX1=128 --> 28k

MAX1=1024 --> 3M
```

these results are not weird any more.

Any new results will be added to this answer in futures updates.